# Docusign API - New Access token do not invalidate the older access token

Tags: docusignapi

While using authorization grant flow for authenticating with Docusign, I am able to generate access token and refresh token.
Now I am using refresh token to get a new pair of access and refresh token. After new Access and refresh tokens are generated, I am able to make calls with older as well as newer access token. This means that new access token generation do not invalidate the older access token. This looks like a bug. Can Docusign Team confirm this. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: I've received information from the engineering team: DocuSign does not invalidate tokens when a new token is requested

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does refresh token also behaves in the same way ? When I generate an access token, a new refresh token is also generated. However, I can use the older refresh token to generate a new access token.

Comment: Reusing the original refresh token is not supported. If it works consider it a fluke. Use the new refresh token you receive when you do the refresh operation.

Answer (score 0):

The access token should last until it expires.

The DocuSign system does not invalidate tokens when a new token is requested.